# openstreetmap->download data... does not download data

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, download, vector-layer

I cannot get the OpenStreetMap -> download data... to actually download.

It acts like there is no problem, says the file is 0MB (it is actually 1KB) and it can be opened as a vector layer, however, the vector layer says there is no data.

I have ensured that it is in EPSG 3857 and the "on-the-fly CRS transformation" is enabled. The scale of the area is 1:500,000 as said by the QGIS website to test this.

The lecturer demonstrated it using 2.14.3 and the file he saved was about 17.5MB so around 17MB is the expected size for this.

Is there any way to work around this? I am using version 2.14.16 64bit
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 1:500,000 seems like a very large area. It's probably too much data.

Comment: I just tested it, didn't work on 1:1000 either. I have just uninstalled 2.14.16 and I was hoping to install 12.14.3 (the one the lecturer uses) but its not there, so I am installing 2.14.9 and hoping it will work

Comment: Does downloading a very (very) small area work?

Comment: 1:100 didn't work

Comment: Just put up a pic of it before it has "success" at downloading nothing

Comment: Same here, seems to be a server break-down. The OSMDownloader plugin does not work either.

Answer (score 4):

There's been a server issue with Overpass API (the engine which provides the data to those plugins) on July 20th. Check the following sites for more details and status updates

- https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/talk/2017-July/078321.html
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/status

Edit: the issue has been resolved in the meantime.